# Building wsp for VS 2013 and SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013, solution-deployment

I am upgrading a VS2008 solution developed for Moss 2007 to VS 2013 for SharePoint 2013.

Initially I upgraded code to VS2010 and now I am doing to VS2013. My solution has 14 projects. I could upgrade and successfully build all the projects in VS2013.

While in VS2010 I used WSPbuilder to create WSP's and deployed on the server. But for VS 2013 I cannot use WSPbuilder as it is targeted for frameworks less than 4.0. Is there any other tool that supports creating WSP's for VS2013.

I cannot use (or I don't see) Publish option as my projects are not SharePoint projects.

Answer (score 1):

WSPbuilder does not support to SharePoint 2013.

Here is the one workaround mentioned here

> If you execute "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application
>   Data\microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins", you should see the WSPBuilder
>   addin file listed.  Simply edit this in notepad (remember to 1) close
>   visual studio and 2) run notepad as admin) and duplicate the two
>   hostapplication nodes - "Microsoft Visual Studio" and "Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Macros", amending the version to "11.0".  Once this is
>   done, you will find that the add-in loads and the context menu will
>   appear.  If you are only intending to use Visual Studio 2012 you
>   could, instead, just update any of the nodes from their existing
>   version to "11.0".

[Not sure, if this work or not](http://gblsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/01/using-wspbuilder-with-visual-studio-2012.html)

Otherwise it is not supported and here are alternate.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41ee2c3b-b5ad-4b2f-a303-b6b0f613a124/sharepoint-2013-wspbuilder-webparts-error?forum=sharepointdevelopment